# Subtraction of subsequent frames in EmguCV 2.2 (cvAbsDiff)

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am using two `QueryFrame` commands one after the other to obtain to frames and calculate their differences using `CvInvoke.cvAbsDiff`. The difference image is always black, although there are visible changes from frame to frame in my video.

I tried skipping up to five frames (by using consecutive `QueryFrame` commands) and always get a black frame.

If I equalize the histogram of one of the two frames, the `AbsDiff` does return a result. Hence I assume that the `QueryFrame` returns the same frame.

How can I obtain two consecutive frames? Any ideas?

Comment: I found a complicated solution... I use `QueryFrame` directly after `new Capture` and store it in a member variable. Then I capture the subsequent frame in a method, which I call using the `Application.Idle`

Comment: It looks more or less like the following:

Comment: `capture = new Capture(@"AnyVideoFile");

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the comments... here comes the solution I found useful:

```
 private Capture myCapture;
 private Image<Bgr, Byte> frame1;
 private Image<Bgr, byte> frame2;

 private void myFunction1() 
 {
   myCapture = new Capture(@"AnyVideoFileName");
   frame1 = myCapture.QueryFrame();
  }

 private void myEventMethod(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
   Application.Idle += myFunction2;
 }

 private void myFunction2(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   frame2 = myCapture.QueryFrame();


   Image<Gray, Byte> frame1g = frame1.Convert<Gray,Byte>();
   Image<Gray, Byte> frame2g = frame2.Convert<Gray,Byte>();
   Image<Gray, Byte> diffFrame = frame2g.Clone();

   CvInvoke.cvAbsDiff(frame1g, frame2g, diffFrame);

   frame1 = frame2.Clone();
 }
```

The above code is just to give you an idea of how it is done. There is no exception handling included, no checks, no optimizations.